# Proving $\sqrt{2a + 2\sqrt{a^2 - b}}=\sqrt{a-\sqrt{b}} + \sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}$, where $a\geq 0,\ b\geq 0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Who can help me to prove this equation?
$$\sqrt{2a + 2\sqrt{a^2 - b}}=\sqrt{a-\sqrt{b}} + \sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}$$ Where, $$a\geq 0,\ b\geq 0$$

Comment: square your equation

Comment: I wouldn't call this equation linear.

Comment: @Xouque55 I tried to simplify left part. But did not succeed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have
$$\left(\sqrt{a-\sqrt{b}}+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}\right)^2 = a-\sqrt{b}+a+\sqrt{b} +2\sqrt{a^2-b} = 2a+2\sqrt{a^2-b}$$

Comment: I fixed equation.

Comment: why did you assume $b^2$ on the left hand side? It should be $b$, right? see the question edited by OP

Comment: @Bhaskara-III He added answer before my correction. Maybe he hasn't seen it yet.

Answer (score 2):

Notice, here is the correct proof $$LHS=\sqrt{2a+2\sqrt{a^2-b}}$$
$$=\sqrt{(a-\sqrt{b})+(a+\sqrt b)+2\sqrt{a^2-(\sqrt b)^2}}$$

$$=\sqrt{\underbrace{\left(\sqrt{a-\sqrt{b}}\right)^2}_{A^2}+\underbrace{\left(\sqrt{a+\sqrt b}\right)^2}_{B^2}+2\underbrace{\sqrt{(a-\sqrt b)}}_{A}\underbrace{\sqrt{(a+\sqrt b)}}_{B}}$$
using identity, $A^2+B^2+2AB=(A+B)^2$, 
$$=\sqrt{\left(\sqrt{a-\sqrt b}+\sqrt{a+\sqrt b}\right)^2}$$
$$=\left|\sqrt{a-\sqrt b}+\sqrt{a+\sqrt b}\right|$$
since, $a\ge 0,\ b\ge 0 $
$$=\sqrt{a-\sqrt b}+\sqrt{a+\sqrt b}$$
$$=RHS$$

Comment: Leg's prove are easier. Your option I saw in the book, but there wasn't any explanations and it was not clear. Now I understand